Is there a scriptable tool to determine whether two periodic structures are the same?
I'm doing some material search, in which I remove 2-4 atoms from a medium sized (~20 atoms) unit cell. I need to find all different combinations that are unique with respect to the translational, rotational and inversion symmetries.
My idea was to generate all combinations first, and then use some readily available algorithm that determines whether two lattice stuctures actually describe the same structure, within a given tolerance (say 0.01Å). However, I was surprised that I could not find such an algorithm.
Are you aware of anything like this?
Ideally, the algorithm would have a Python interface, to which I could pass the ASE Atoms objects or the coordinates I'm working with. Alternatively, it's also acceptable if it requires two structure files (ideally .cif) as an input, or any other format. The only restriction is that the workflow has to be automated, as there will be thousands of structures eventually. If it's of any concern, my structure is 2D graphene like.

The answers here might be useful

@RashidRafeek Indeed they are! Thanks for the suggestion. I did find one of the recommendations there, pymatgen, independently in the meantime, but the algorithm proved to be rather slow for my needs - taking 1.5 seconds for two ~35 atom unit cells, when I have to make tens of thousands of comparisons.

Check your options to access the CSD database provided by the Cambridge Crystallographic Data Centre (CCDC)* -- even if the structures you eventually want to compare with each other are not materials of small organic/organometallic molecules (which discerns the CSD file for instance from the ISCD about inorganic structures, or the COD to accept records from both communities).  In addition to the freely/community edition of CCDC's Mercury GUI to display structures, the full CSD license (then subscription based) access additionally provides a Python API to offer a programmatic analysis of crystal structure data, and environment of R (statistical analysis).  With a proper setup, the Python API can be accessed both from the command line, or from Mercury (cross platform; Windows/Linux/Mac).
In line what you look for the API provides e.g., routines to easier retrieve similar structures on molecular level, and an other at the level of crystal packing (for instance identification of polymorphs).  The later is based on the COMPACK algorithm by Chisholm and Motherwell.  The standardized syntax of .cif files (see IUCr's documentation) allows to process non CSD datasets by the CSD Python API, too.
In addition to a literature research searching for publications citing this specific work, structure comparison, similarity searching, and crystal packing are keywords about publications in the journals by the International Union of Crystallography --  series of Acta Crystallographica (more leaning on application of algorithms, general entry) complemented, e.g. by Journal of Applied Crystallography (more leaning to the implementation of algorithms to benefit of crystallography into computer programs, including machine learning).
Chisholm, J. A.; Motherwell, S. COMPACK: A Program for Identifying Crystal Structure Similarity Using Distances. J. Appl. Crystallogr. 2005, 38 (1), 228–231. https://doi.org/10.1107/S0021889804027074.
* Sometimes an individual group purchases a license of such a database ([chemical] crystallography, [solid state] physics, materials science, geology, [inorganic] chemistry, biology, etc).  Other times, a research library organizes a consortium of multiple research groups/institutes to provide access to the CSD file as an additional database in the physics/chemistry section.
Addition: one of the more recently published programs to compare packing similarities of molecular crystals is CrystalCMP where the same molecular structure optionally can be described by a SMILES string.  The implementation runs from a GUI as a program for the Windows operating system and the manual mentions that it can be run header less/from the command line, too (so might be launched by Python's popen/os.subprocess).  In addition to quantify (dis)similarity of packings to populate an array of data (pairwise comparison), similar to the scripts by CCDC, more similar packings become closer neighbors than other in a subsequent dendrogram (see two demo videos on youtube, and literature citing the seminal work).  It has been successfully used for the comparison of data sets of multiple thousand cif files.
If you identify a few of particularly interesting packing pattern, the recently published hints on visualizing them with tools provided by the Bilbao Crystallographic Server, Mercury, Vesta and Jmol may help you, too.
Rohlíček, J.; Skořepová, E.; Babor, M.; Čejka, J. CrystalCMP : An Easy-to-Use Tool for Fast Comparison of Molecular Packing. J. Appl. Crystallogr. 2016, 49 (6), 2172–2183. https://doi.org/10.1107/S1600576716016058.
Rohlíček, J.; Skořepová, E. CrystalCMP : Automatic Comparison of Molecular Structures. J. Appl. Crystallogr. 2020, 53 (3), 841–847. https://doi.org/10.1107/S1600576720003787.
De La Flor, G.; Aroyo, M. I.; Gimondi, I.; Ward, S. C.; Momma, K.; Hanson, R. M.; Suescun, L. Free Tools for Crystallographic Symmetry Handling and Visualization. J. Appl. Crystallogr. 2024, 57 (5). https://doi.org/10.1107/S1600576724007659 (open access).

Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately we do not have such license, neither the means to allocate funding for it, so it's not a solution for me. Our only options are free software.

I'll amend the answer if travel to a state university/research library which has access and check if they can grant access as an adjunct member of faculty (within a project's cooperation)/as walk-in user isn't an option.  Sad state of funding (since compared to other research databases like Reaxys or Scifinder, a 1 year FTE license of the CSD is very affordable).

The answer was amended by CrystalCMP as an example of a freely available program for the packing analysis of (molecular) crystals, and a publication around the BCS, Vesta, Mercury and Jmol for crystallography announced just a few days ago on the Jmol user list.

I've accepted the answer by @Buttonwood, which contains a lot of very useful resources. I thought it may be useful to share how I eventually solved the issue.
Exact, slow method
The most suitable tool I found was pymatgen.analysis.StructureMatcher from the Pymatgen library. This creates a fingerprint of the material by checking local environments, atomic distances, and whatelse, all while considering the full periodic symmetry of the structure. An example of using this to compare two structures, represented by an ase.Atoms:
import ase
from pymatgen.analysis.structure_matcher import StructureMatcher
from pymatgen.io.ase import AseAtomsAdaptor

def is_same_struct(s1: ase.Atoms, s2: ase.Atoms, ltol=0.01, stol=0.01, angle_tol=0.01, **kwargs):
    s1_pmg = AseAtomsAdaptor.get_structure(s1)
    s2_pmg = AseAtomsAdaptor.get_structure(s2)
    matcher = StructureMatcher(ltol=ltol, stol=stol, angle_tol=angle_tol, **kwargs)
    return matcher.fit(s1_pmg, s2_pmg)

However, I found this to be way too slow for my needs. StructureMatcher took me more than 0.2 second to compare two structures with 20 atoms each - and I need tens of thousands of comparisons!
Fast approximate method (for rough filtering)
Therefore, I implemented a fast check that only considers:

the total stochiometry,
the interatomic PBC distances,
optionally the lattice parameters,
and optionally the symmetry group.

Fundamentally, the code calculates and compares the atom-atom distance matrix, which is invariant to symmetry transformations. This matrix is flattened and sorted in an ascending way. If the two sorted arrays are equal within a tolerance, the structures are considered similar:
import ase
import spglib

def is_similar_struct_diffs(
        s1: ase.Atoms, 
        s2: ase.Atoms, 
        tol: float = 0.01, 
        ctol: Optional[float] = None, 
        test_cell=True, 
        test_sym=True, 
        elements: List[str] = None
        ) -> bool:
    """
    Checks if two atomic structures are similar based on cell parameters, symmetry, and interatomic distances.

    Args:
        s1 (ase.Atoms): The first structure to compare.
        s2 (ase.Atoms): The second structure to compare.
        tol (float, optional): Tolerance for interatomic distance differences and symmetry precision. Defaults to 0.01.
        ctol (float, optional): Tolerance for cell parameter differences. If None, defaults to `tol`. Defaults to None.
        test_cell (bool, optional): Whether to compare the cell parameters. Defaults to True.
        test_sym (bool, optional): Whether to compare the symmetry group symbols. Defaults to True.
        elements (list of str, optional): List of element symbols to consider when comparing positions. If None, all atoms are considered.

    Returns:
        bool: True if the structures are similar within the given tolerances, False otherwise.

    Raises:
        ValueError: If the two structures have different periodic boundary conditions.

    Notes:
        - **Caveats**:
            - The algorithm does not distinguish between different elements at the same positions. Exchanging different atoms while preserving stoichiometry may result in the structures being falsely considered similar.
            - If the sorted interatomic distances remain unchanged between two different systems (e.g., due to local symmetry), they may be considered similar even if they are not.
            - Angles are not considered; in certain cases, especially with non-3D periodicity, this could result in false positives.
        - If you expect any of these cases, consider using an exact matching method after this to confirm matches.
    """
    if not np.array_equal(s1.pbc, s2.pbc):
       raise ValueError("The two structures have different periodicity")

    # Check stoichiometry
    if s1.get_chemical_formula() != s2.get_chemical_formula():
        return False

    # check cell
    ctol = tol if ctol is None else ctol
    cell1, cell2 = s1.cell, s2.cell
    if test_cell and not np.all(np.abs(cell1 - cell2) < ctol):
        return False

    # test symmetry
    if test_sym:
        dataset1 = spglib.get_symmetry_dataset(ase2spg(s1), symprec=tol)
        dataset2 = spglib.get_symmetry_dataset(ase2spg(s2), symprec=tol)
        if dataset1.number != dataset2.number:
            return False

    if elements is not None:
        indices1 = [i for i, atom in enumerate(s1) if atom.symbol in elements]
        indices2 = [i for i, atom in enumerate(s2) if atom.symbol in elements]

        # Check that the number of selected atoms is the same
        if len(indices1) != len(indices2):
            return False

        # Extract positions of the selected atoms
        positions1 = s1.get_positions()[indices1]
        positions2 = s2.get_positions()[indices2]
    else:
        # Consider all atoms
        positions1 = s1.get_positions()
        positions2 = s2.get_positions()
        if len(positions1) != len(positions2):
            return False

    d1 = get_all_pbc_dists(positions1, cell1, pbc=s1.pbc)
    d2 = get_all_pbc_dists(positions2, cell2, pbc=s2.pbc)
    return np.all(np.abs(d2 - d1) < tol)

def get_all_pbc_dists(structure: ase.Atoms):
    "Get all interatomic distances in the structure with periodic boundary condtions as a sorted array"
    dists_matrix = atoms.get_all_distances(mic=True)

    # Extract the upper triangle of the distance matrix (since it's symmetric)
    i_upper = np.triu_indices(len(positions), k=1)
    dists = dists_matrix[i_upper]
    return np.sort(dists)


This code is almost 50x faster than the exact one using StructureMatcher, taking only a mere 4ms for the same systems. However, it comes with a cost:

Caveat 1: this algorithm, as I implemented, does not distinguish between different elements at the same locations. If you exchange two different atoms while preserving the stochiometry, the structures will be tested as the same.

Caveat 2: Similarly, if the (sorted) distances remain unchanged between two differnt systems - for example, due to a local symmetry - they will be tested similar even if they are actually not the same.

Caveat 3: Angles are not considered. In certain edge cases, or in case of non-3D periodicity, this could also result in false positives.


If you except any of these cases, calling the exact method afterwards may be neccessary to be certain about a match. Even if exact matching is required, this can be used for pre-screening before applying a slower exact matching algorithm.
Benchmarking
Comparing two simple 2D structures (a reduced graphene oxide with two oxygen in a 4x4 unit cell), the execution time is as follows:
time_exact = timeit.timeit(lambda: is_same_struct(s1, s2), number=20)
time_approx = timeit.timeit(lambda: is_similar_struct_diffs(s1, s2), number=20)

print(f"Stochiometries: s1: {s1.get_chemical_formula()}, {s2.get_chemical_formula()}")
print(f"Exact method time per call: {time_exact / 20 * 1000:.2f} ms")
print(f"Approximate method time per call: {time_approx / 20 * 1000:.2f} ms")

Stochiometries: s1: C32O, s2: C32O
Exact method time per call: 207.05 ms
Approximate method time per call: 4.15 ms


Within the USPEX code there is a function called Fingerprint. From the site:

Fingerprint function is a crystal structure descriptor, a 1D-function related to the pair correlation function and diffraction patterns. It does not depend on absolute atomic coordinates, but only on interatomic distances. Small deviations in atomic positions will influence fingerprints only slightly.

There are two online versions that can be used for only one POSCARS file or for a gathered POSCARS:

Fingerprints 2.0 (single file): https://uspex-team.org/online_utilities/fingerprints2/
Multifingerprint (one gathered file): https://uspex-team.org/online_utilities/multifingerprint/

